# React router dom not rendering the conditional routes (login and auth)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I have a login page and an auth page (a private page). I render them conditionally, so when the user if authenticaded, it redirects it to go to render that routes and not the login routes.

The problem is that when in the URL, I put /settings (the user s authenticated), it doesn't render it, instead, it redirects me to ./404 (which I made when it finds that the route doesn't exist, but this route exists).

There is the following code from the files:

*./App.js*

```
...
render() {
    let Routing;
    if (!this.state.loading_auth) {
      if (this.state.auth) {
        Routing = <Dashboard auth={this.state.auth} />;
      } else {
        Routing = <Init auth={this.state.auth} />;
      }
    } else if (this.props.loading || this.state.loading_auth) {
      Routing = <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    }

    return <BrowserRouter>{Routing}</BrowserRouter>;
  }
...
```

*./Dashboard.js*

```
...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <MainPage auth={this.props.auth} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/settings">
            <Settings />
          </Route>
          <Route
            path="/404"
            render={() => (
              <h1>
                Page not found, auth, go <Link to="/">home</Link>
              </h1>
            )}
          />
          <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
```

*./Init.js*

```
...
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <LandingPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signup">
            <SignupPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/forget">
            <Forget />
          </Route>
          <Route
            path="/404"
            render={() => (
              <h1>
                Page not found, not auth, go <Link to="/">home</Link>
              </h1>
            )}
          ></Route>
          <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Where am I doing wrong? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I've checked your code. authenticated user with `/settings` route loads the settings page! but unauthenticated user went to 404 page.do you want unauthenticated user renders the to login page?

Comment: It doesn't render the /settings when the user is authenticated, that is the problem, it redirects to /404. even if the user is authenticated.

Comment: check this sample please https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-0xq6u